# Error on executing a function in a AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, progress

Im trying to load some images from a URL.

I have a private void that makes all the work. It works... but i have a problem, i want to show a dialog progress while my images are loading...

I am trying with an AsyncTask but i have a problem when executing the doInBackground!

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new EjecutarTarea().execute();



}


    private  void Principal() {
    //Code to download images from URL
    }


    public class EjecutarTarea extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(StadioNenaActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando..");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Unsed) {

      Principal();  //i have an error here 
      return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Thanks for the help !.

---

This is the error on de log... it return null in some part of my code PRINCIPAL() ....

i dont know why, when i put PRINCIPAL in Oncreate, it works great!.

```
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907): java.lang.RuntimeException: An      error    occured while executing doInBackground()
    10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done  (AsyncTask.java:200)
    10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
  10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
  10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
  10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
  10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at Stadio.bacha.stadionena.StadioNenaActivity.Principal(StadioNenaActivity.java:121)
  10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at Stadio.bacha.stadionena.StadioNenaActivity$EjecutarTarea.doInBackground(StadioNenaActivity.java:262)
10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at Stadio.bacha.stadionena.StadioNenaActivity$EjecutarTarea.doInBackground(StadioNenaActivity.java:1)
10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-10 17:56:01.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10907):     ... 4 more
```

When i go like this:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Principal();

}
```

it works, but it does not show dialog progress...

Comment: What is your error, print a stack trace. Empty methods don't generally error.

Comment: The error seems to be inside principal, so you might wanna show us its code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a NullPointerException when `doInBackground()` is called. Ensure that all data is available before calling `AsyncTask.execute()` or provide some kind of blocking mechanism.

Comment: Im trying to get all the data in doInBackground  (executing PRINCIPAL)

Comment: But there is something missing that `Principal()` needs, this part of the stack trace shows that missing part `StadioNenaActivity.java:121`.

Comment: (im new to android, sorry for that).  Yeah, im understandig that, but why does it work great if i just use PRINCIPAL in  OnCreate  ?...

Comment: The nature of `doInBackground` vs `onCreate` are different because `doInBackground` runs in a separate Thread. The important part is this line: `StadioNenaActivity.java:121` because that's where the error occurs.

Comment: this is the code
        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Principal();

}

Answer (score 0):

make sure your url is correct.
I got this error because i used 192.168.1.173/webroot path... 
I mean withour http:// part as url.
After I tried with

```
http://192.168.1.173/web application path ...
```

it works fine.